# Passing variable from controller to model functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, controller

Hi Im stucked with this for 4 days now, i have read massive amount of related articles, but seems nothing is working.
First i will explain my idea, give you some code and then i will tell what i have tried.
Idea. I have 2 separate db tables 'project' and 'pictures'. In project table i put info about projects (id, title, pubdate, template etc.) and i need to assign some pictures to that project so on pictures table i have "project_id" column which is relating those two. In my controller i have function project_picture_proccess($id) this $id is changing according to which project im clicking on and that is how all related pictures are fetched. problem is i cant pass that current project $id to upload model (this is for setting upload path for current project). 
This is my controller:

```
   class project extends Admin_Controller{
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('project_m');
    $this->load->model('project_pictures_m');

   //here is index() function and some other (not related to my problem)

public function project_picture_proccess($id = NULL){
    //$id variable is from current project im editing
    //and changes according to project id

    $this->load->model('upload_m');

    if ($id) {
        //search for directory in upload path with current project slug name
        //and if there isnt any it will create it and add proper rights
        $this->project_m->search_and_create_dir($id);

        //function get_images is fetching all images that current project has
        $this->data['project_images'] = $this->project_m->get_images($id);

        //this function is setting upload config (setting upload path
        //based on directory created in above)-its working var_dump'ed it
        $this->upload_m->set_upload_config($id);

    }


    if($this->input->post('upload')){
        //do_multi_upload works on multiple images just fine
        //but i cant make it to get outcome of set_upload_config function
        //so i can set upload_path very manualy and everything i upload is in mess
        $this->upload_m->do_multi_upload();

        //redirection function does not work because it is not getting 
        //any project_m data and i have lost all project_m related data in my view
        //its title of project im editing and its id
        redirect('admin/project/project_picture_proccess');
    }


    $this->data['error'] = array('error' => '');
    $this->data['project'] = $this->project_m->get($id);

    //function get_images is fetching all unsorted images uploaded in 
    //the path created above for further proccessing
    $this->data['unsorted_img'] = $this->upload_m->get_unsorted();

    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/project/picture_proccess';

    $this->load->view('admin/main', $this->data);
}
```

and here is my model:

```
class Upload_m extends MY_model{

protected $pic_path;
protected $_primary_filter = 'intval';
protected $_table_name = 'projects';

function Upload_m(){

    parent::__construct();

    $this->pic_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../img/');

 function get_slug($id = NULL){
    if($id !=NULL){
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);

        $result = mysql_query('SELECT slug FROM ' . $this->_table_name . ' WHERE id=' . $id . ' limit 1');
        $data = mysql_fetch_row($result);

        $name = array_shift($data); //array - need to be string

        return $name;

    }else return;
}
 function set_upload_config($id){
    if($id == NULL) return;
    $slug = $this->get_slug($id);
    $upload_config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|gif|jpeg|png|bmp',
        'upload_path' => $this->pic_path . $slug . '/',
        'max_size' => 0
    );
    return $upload_config;
}
 function do_multi_upload(){
    $this->load->library('upload');        

    $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_config());
    if($this->upload->do_multi_upload('userfile')){

        var_dump($this->upload->get_multi_upload_data());
        return;
    }else echo "Error at uploading";      
}
```

Here is what i have tried:

1. moving `if($this->input->post...)` method inside if($id) scope and
   nothing is passed to view and noting is passed to model
2. tried like every single solution on stackoverflow: [these](https://www.google.lv/#q=passing%20variables%20from%20controller%20to%20model%20codeigniter) very common tip was `$this->load->model('upload_m', $id)` <-
   returning null when var_dump($id) tested on `function
   do_something($id){var_dump($id); die;}`
3. i have made global variables and tried to fetch them by get_class_vars
4. i have rewrite system/core/libraries/model function to accept variable on `do_multi_upload($field<-this is default,
   $var=NULL<-optional)`
5. i have tried to put those variables in __construct() function like __construct($var)
6. i have tried to change name of that $id to $var and put it inside `if($this->input->post('upload') && $var === $id)` and tried to use $var in model.  didnt work this approach

I am so desperate this has taken too too much my time. My goal is to pass $id to upload function to set correct upload path and save data into database url (taken from upload_path), project_id ->taken from passed $id. Any help will be appreciated even if its a suggestion how to change my structure so i could still meet my goals.

Comment: When you ``dump($id)`` in ``project::project_picture_proccess()`` what you see? Value of ``$id`` was passed to method?

Comment: yes i see it till end of first if statement.

Comment: Maybe someone could help me to create a different architecture for my project? Idea is simple for each project i need to store images about it, but they must be  separated in categories, e.g. for project "house" i need to have separate images for "blueprints", "interior", "piping" etc. those categories must be created dynamically for each project im writing about. Just a single idea or a tip will be appreciated.